# Solr removing the 'e' from ace001 search term

Tags: solr, lucene

Solr is removing the letter 'e' from search queries...

I'm pretty new when it comes to Solr so I don't really know where to start looking to figure this out but whenever I send a search query Solr is stripping out the 'e' character...

As you can see here when I try and search the term `ace001`

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "q": "_text:ace001",
      "indent": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "debugQuery": "true",
      "_": "1478467316690"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "_text:ace001",
    "querystring": "_text:ace001",
    "parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(_text:\"ac 001 ac 001\")",
    "parsedquery_toString": "_text:\"ac 001 ac 001\"",
    "explain": {},
    "QParser": "LuceneQParser",
    "timing": {
      "time": 1,
      "prepare": {
        "time": 1,
        "query": {
          "time": 1
        },
        "facet": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "mlt": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "highlight": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "stats": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "spellcheck": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "debug": {
          "time": 0
        }
      },
      "process": {
        "time": 0,
        "query": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "facet": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "mlt": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "highlight": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "stats": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "spellcheck": {
          "time": 0
        },
        "debug": {
          "time": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Searching a different term such as 'acb001' doesn't strip the 'b' but I noticed it does separate the numbers from the letters. I'd want Solr to match the term 'acb001' in the text field...

extract:

```
"rawquerystring": "_text:acb001",
"querystring": "_text:acb001",
"parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(_text:\"acb 001 acb 001\")",
"parsedquery_toString": "_text:\"acb 001 acb 001\"",
"explain": {},
"QParser": "LuceneQParser",
```

Would really appreciate some direction here as to how I can either further debug or ideally fix this so ace001 returns all the occurrences of just that.

Edit:

Schema is standard/default http://pastebin.com/59LbmJUp

Comment: can you post your schema.xml ?

Comment: I'm guessing your analyzer involves an WordDelimiterFilter and a stemmer, so "ace001" gets separated into "ace" and "001", then "ace" gets stemmed to "ac".

Comment: @femtoRgon I'd say you're right, I'm just trying to workout how to stop it from doing it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is happening because of solr.PorterStemFilterFactory. your default search field id is htmltext which has
`<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>`

in the query analysis.

the PorterStemmer stems the word "ace" to "ac".
you can check it here  https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/voc.txt
search for the word "ace". 
now look here which has corresponding output after stemming https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/output.txt  the corresponding word after stemming which will be "ac"

to solve this revmoe the filter during query as well as index in solrconfig.xml

Also you are using **WordDelimiterFilterFactory**, which will split words on alphanumeric bounderies. that is why you see "ac" and "001", if you do not want that then remove that filter too in schema.xml

you are using default schema.xml which has a lot of these unnecessary filters which you  might not even need. I would suggest to strip it down to a few filters. and then add filters as you need instead of the other way.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've removed all traces of PorterStemFilterFactory from schema.xml and I couldn't find any in solrconfig.xml but I'm still getting exactly the same results;

Comment: have you reloaded the core ?